# Spritekit OS X how to use custom fonts

Tags: macos, fonts, sprite-kit

I am making a sprite kit game for OSX using swift. I am trying to custom font for my SKLabelNodes but they just show arial (the default font).
What I have tried:

- adding the font to FontsProvidedByApplication in ino.plist
- In buildphases, dragging it into copy bundle resources

The font is a .ttf font. I already have this font working in the iOS version of my game using the steps above.

-Thanks for any help

EDIT: the code I am using is just this:

```
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "fontname")
```

- The font has been added to the OS X target of my game.
- The font is working for the iOS target

Comment: Where is your related code?

Comment: keep in mind that filename is not (necessarily) the font family name of the font, see the iosfonts website for examples

Comment: When you drag the font in to Xcode make sure to check your project in add to target.  It is sometimes unchecked by default

Comment: Like LearnCocos2D said, filename is not necessarily the font family name. Use your Fontbook to see the real name, or do it programatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a checklist of what to do...

1. Add the font to your app bundle
2. Add the "Application fonts resource path" key to Info.plist with "Fonts" as the value
3. Create a Copy build phase with "Resources" as the Destination and "Fonts" as the Subpath
4. Drag/Drop the font to the Copy build phase
5. In Finder, right-click on the font file and select the "Get Info" menu option. From the "Full Name" field, copy the font's name and paste it into the following

   `let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"{font name here}")`

[image]